# Сет данных в модель перед сохранением

Tags: laravel

Помогите разобраться.

Как в Laravel 5+ нужно правильно сетить данные в модель перед добавлением новой записи?

Сейчас я делаю вот так. Ниже код:

```
$comment = new Comment();        

$comment->user_name = $input['userName'];
$comment->email = $input['email'];
$comment->home_page = $input['homePage'] ?? null;
$comment->text = $input['message'];
$comment->parent_id = $input['parent_id'] ?? 0;
$comment->level = $input['level'] ?? 0;
$comment->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$comment->browser = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

$comment->save();
```

Делаю сет всех аттрибутов модели и вызываю метод save для создания новой записи.
Как можно сделать это лучше, чище и компактнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну... Пожалуй, как-то так можно

```
$args = array(
    'user_name' => $input['userName'],
    'email' => $input['email'],
    ...
);
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->fill($args);
$comment->save();
\\ или же заменить предыдущие строки можно одной: 
\\ $comment = Comment::create($args);
```

> UPD. Забыл добавить, если использовать `fill()` то в модели надо
>   объявить переменную `$fillable` с указанием массива полей которые
>   могут заполняться данным методом

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь )